# Assembly Load issues "Could not load type XYZ from Assembly ABC

Tags: c#, .net, loading

Given:

Example Namesspaces by projects in a solution.

1. BaseNameSpace
2. BaseNameSpace.Reports

I realized that I needed to "collapse" the Reports namespace and put it into the base.  I still want the project to be it's own project.  The properties for project 2 above look like this:

[image]

If Change those values to this:

[image]

Any attempts to use the Reports in another project e.g.

1. BaseNameSpace.AnotherProjectRoot

Issues the message in title. Now here's the funny thing, intellisense finds the classes needed, but the run time loader doesn't....

Can't *multiple projects* in same solution contain the same namespace? It's almost as if the loader find the base namespace in one project, but will not use the other project (with a different name) but same Namespace...

Comment: Do you have references to all assemblies? The CLR loads assemblies, not namespaces.

Comment: The solution should because the projects are all in same solution, I'll go back and check all of the assembly names

Comment: Does any of the other projects in the solution also have a Assembly name: of `BaseNameSpace` by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Attempting to change a namespace results in compile errors are reference errors.

**Solution**

Right click on each project and choose Properties.  Click on the Application button at top and ensure the Target Framework for each project is the same.

**Symptoms**

The symptoms when you have this issue are:  1) Intellisense easily finds the methods within the other projects 2)Right clicking on a method referenced in another project and picking Go to Definition works fine. 3) Compiling the solution will show reference errors saying something like could not find namespace xyz in assembly.  4) Looking at the references in each project will show Yellow warning signs even though those other references are "by solution".  You attempt to correct by re-pointing to the other project in solution and the Yellow flag remains.

**Root Cause**

Not known as we merely changed a namespace name in a project that previously had NONE of these errors.  We did not change .NET versions ever!